# Xcode 5 [NSString writeToFile] without absolute path

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I've checked out a few other posts about this topic, but I am still left with some doubt on whether or not [NSString writeToFile] is writing to the relative path.

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [str writeToFile:@"someFile.txt"
                     atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          error:&error];

NSString *status = success ? @"Success" : @"Failure";
    if(success){
        NSLog(@"Done Writing: %@",status);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Done Writing: %@",status);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

writeToFile works when given the path to a certain folder and by NSLogging the error, I can see what kind of error occurs.  However, when running the above code, no error occurs and after having done a thorough search, I *think* I can safely say that a file was never created.  What's going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's certainly *working*, which you confirm yourself as your code traps and reports errors very nicely.  Your only issue is that you don't know *where* the file is being written to, and in this case, as no path has been specified it will be to the *current working directory*, which is a concept in pretty much all operating systems (even Windows!).

I must admit that I don't know what the default *current working directory* is under iOS, but you can find out yourself with:

```
NSString *cwd = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
NSLog(@"cwd='%@'", cwd);
```

Comment: @dbarcklow Out of interest, what was the *cwd*?

Comment: `cwd='/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>-cvobckxnbewqoiaocedjdmgtjeis/Build/Products/Debug'`

I'm not sure what the extra characters are, but it ended up being within the hidden User Library folder../sigh

Comment: @dbarcklow OK, so that's under the Simulator, how about on a real device?

Comment: It's a command-line tool, I'm not sure what you mean by real device. Is there a way to check?